# Python 2.7 twisted FileSender ProducerMembrane object was never unregistered

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I have client periodically upload files to the server by using FileSender in twisted. If the last upload task haven't finished and the current upload starts, I receive an runtime exception shows:

Cannot register producer , because producer  was never registered.

My code is like follows:

```
def uploadFile(self, filename):
    try:
        self.sender = FileSender()
        d = self.sender.beginFileTransfer(uploadfile, self.transport, self.__monitor)
        d.addCallback(self.uploadCompleted, filename)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        ...
```

My question is how to avoid this error? If we cannot avoid it, how to recover from it? Right now, if it happens once, the uploadFile will never send file any more.

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/ and update your question with the additional details necessary for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

Now I strictly skip the current upload task until the last upload task has finished. And it works!